# PHP regex for @[mention]

Tags: php, regex

Can someone help me:

```
$pattern = "/^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9?. ]?)+@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(.+)?$/";
$str = "Hey @[14256] hey how are you?";
preg_match($pattern, $title, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The print result works fine if I remove the brackets (@[14256]) of the @ mention, however I can't figure out how to do the regex to work with the brackets. So I will get the result 14256 in my array.

Comment: You mean, adding brackets to your character class?

Comment: In my regex, so one of my results in the array will be 14256. Which works fine if I do $str = "Hey @14256 hey how are you?"; but not with $str = "Hey @[14256] hey how are you?";

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to include the brackets in your regex:

```
"/^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9?. ]?)+@(\\[?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\]?)(.+)?$/"
```

Notice the `\\[?` and `\\]?` I've added; those will match the `[]` characters, and will also match if there is no `[]`.

Keep in mind, the above will match `@[14256` and `@14256]`. If you want to only match one or the other, you need to do it a little differently.

```
"/^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9?. ]?)+@([a-zA-Z0-9]+|\\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\])(.+)?$/"
```

This will match EITHER `@aA1` *or* `@[aA1]`, but not the bad examples as I showed above.

One last thing to include: This regex will only match one instance of the `@[mention]`. If you want to match ALL instances of it (such as in "*hey @123, how is @456 these days?*"), use the following with `preg_match_all()`:

```
"/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+|\\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\])/"
```

Then `$matches[1]` will contain both `123` and `456`.

Comment: You have to use it with [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) or it only returns one result.

Comment: Sorry I think it's better I go to bed! wasn't really awake! Thank you very much!

Comment: oooh however this "/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+|\\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\])/" return with brackets, what do I have to add to make sure the result is only the number and no brackets? Thanks

Comment: That gets substantially trickier in terms of regex. Just call `trim($result, "[]");` on the resulting string after the regex is complete.

Comment: Thanks! `me@me.me` would be matched as well, `"/(?<![a-zA-Z])@([a-zA-Z0-9]+|\\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\])/"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the brackets in your regex so they don't get interpreted as a new character class.  Try this instead (it will only capture the number, not the brackets.  Place the escaped brackets in the parentheses to capture them as part of a backreference):

```
$pattern = "/^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9?. ]?)+@\[([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\](.+)?$/";
```